# iphone 6 iOS 9.2.1 HTML in webview doesnt redraw properly

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, webview

I've recently encountered this mind-boggling bug in a hybrid app using `HTML5`, `CSS3`, and `JS`. I have only one `HTML file` with 2 elements that act like pages. Using only classes to toggle the display of the two.

HTML:

```html
<div id='one'class='page'></div>
<div id='two' class='page active-page'></div>
```

CSS:

```css
.page{ display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.page.active-page{ display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

JS:

```
$(elementTrigger).on('tap', function(e){
   $('.active-page').removeClass('active-page');
   $(pageToDisplay).addClass('active-page');
}); /* using Tocca.js and jquery for tap events */
```

Simple right? WRONG! On the first try, I can get to page two from page one and vice versa without any problems. The problem occurs on the second attempt. Tap events don't seem to work. Tested on the actual phone and monitored via XCode and safari web inspector. No error on the console. When I tried manually moving the 'active-page' class it didn't display properly. CSS styles weren't applied and hovering on HTML elements on Safari web inspector showed the wrong position of boxes.

It only triggers on an iPhone 6/6+ with an iOS version of 9.2.1. All other iPhones with the same version and tested the same way work perfectly fine. Android works fine, BTW.

I need help. Any suggestions?